# I can't login to facebook from any browser

Tags: proxy, facebook, tor

I'm Using UBUNTU 12.04.
I'm having problems with Facebook. It really hard to login. Takes like 3 or 5 min. At first I thought it was a flash problem but then I realized it could be some proxy's conf file. Other sites doesn't have problems.

Yesterday I tried Tor-browser-bundle and I installed privoxy using this rules http://www.neilvandyke.org/privoxy-rules/ . 
Today I removed privoxy and the conf file with the Ubuntu software center and ubuntu-tweak.

I don't really find the problem and my windows pc does not have any problem with the same modem. I don't have an ISP'S PROXY it just a direct Internet connection using automatic DHCP.

Maybe I am missing something else. But I want to be sure so, I'm  asking.

Comment: try to check you networking settings and put in on automatic...

Comment: i tried but still not work. I didn't mention but with chrome and chromium i log into facebook faster than with Firefox but the chat show me the chat connection problem message.

Comment: I have this problem with logging in Ask Ubuntu via Firefox, when I use Chrome everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly related to Ubuntu not networks or firewall and affects a huge number of users. Just Google it.

Inside same network and machine I tested running Firefox and Chrome in 12.04 x64 and Windows 7 x64, with dual-boot. Everything is working fine in the Windows 7 boot.

Also tested with VirtualBox, 12.04 x64 host and Windows 7 x64 as guest. The host, Ubuntu cannot connect, times out, no data received, etc. to Facebook (Chrome and Firefox). The guest, Windows 7 runs everything fine.